# Objective-C libraries wrapping Core Text / Core Image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-text, catiledlayer, core-image

Drawing large scrollable content with CATiledLayer works great in my application. What does not work so great is drawing images and multiline text with the Core Text and Core Image APIs in C.

I have the strong feeling that I'm trying to reinvent the wheel, writing my own Objective-C wrapper classes around the C functions like `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`, mirroring everything with `CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1))` etc, etc, etc.

I can't use UIKit's context draw methods, because they cause race-condition crashes due to the concurrent background drawing in CATiledLayer.

What Objective-C libraries are already out there, that wrap the Core Text and Image functions for ease of use in a background context?

Cheers, EP.

**UPDATE: The way things are going now, I will also settle for hints at a book or online resource *other than the Apple Docs* that extensively describe CoreText.**

Comment: Core Text isn't really popular, ey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a week later I have come no closer to finding a library, although the list of libraries at [cocoaobjects.com](http://cocoaobjects.com/) is very comprehensive. I have written my own wrappers now, even though it feels redundant.

What helped a lot was [chapter 5 of the book "Beginning iPad development for iPhone developers: Mastering the iPad SDK"](http://books.google.nl/books?id=mTGLGxnth0YC&lpg=PA100&ots=S7bXXaEz06&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false). It has a very nice introduction to Core Text, especially with the block pointing out the toll-free bridging and the opaque C-types.

Comment: have you considered sharing them on github?

Comment: Yes, but they'd be vastly outdated by now. There are a lot of CoreText wrapping libraries out there. Have a look over at http://cocoapods.org/?q=coretext.

Comment: Thanks, it would be worth updating your answer with that link.